Angular 17 with Angular-Datatables: Unable to Re-render DataTable
I'm working on an Angular 17 application using Angular-Datatables, and I'm having trouble re-rendering the DataTable when updating the data after a search. Below is the relevant code for my component:
html
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search by title" />
  <button (click)="searchPosts()">Search</button>
</div>

<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


Ts file
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  posts: any[] = [];
  searchTerm: string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      destroy: true
    };

    // Fetch initial data
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.dtTrigger.next(null);
      });
  }

  searchPosts(): void {
    if (this.searchTerm.trim() === '') {
      this.fetchData(); // If search term is empty, fetch all data
    } else {
      this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?title_like=${this.searchTerm}`)
        .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
          this.posts = posts;
          this.dtTrigger.next(null); // Re-render the DataTable
        });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}


Problem:
I am unable to re-render the DataTable with updated data when performing a search. I have checked the documentation  and tried various approaches, including triggering the dtTrigger in ngAfterViewInit, but it didn’t work.
Doc link: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-ajax
I also attempted to implement a rerender method like this:
rerender() {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then(dtInstance => {
    dtInstance.destroy();
    this.dtTrigger.next(null);
  });
}


Note:
I am using Angular 17 and the latest version of Angular-Datatables. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

To properly re-render the DataTable after updating the data in Angular-Datatables, you need to ensure that you are correctly handling the lifecycle of the DataTable instance. Here’s a detailed approach to resolving the issue:

Modify your TypeScript file to use @ViewChild and implement the re-render method
Update the HTML to use Angular's ViewChild for the DataTable



import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false }) dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  posts: any[] = [];
  searchTerm: string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      destroy: true
    };

    // Fetch initial data
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.dtTrigger.next(null);
      });
  }

  searchPosts(): void {
    if (this.searchTerm.trim() === '') {
      this.fetchData(); // If search term is empty, fetch all data
    } else {
      this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?title_like=${this.searchTerm}`)
        .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
          this.posts = posts;
          this.rerender();
        });
    }
  }

  rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.destroy();
      this.dtTrigger.next(null);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search by title" />
  <button (click)="searchPosts()">Search</button>
</div>

<table #dataTable datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Hope this will work for you :)

above is  not working and result is still same

Below is the repo
https://github.com/mehulk05/angular-datatable

Maybe changes are not being detected, try calling detectChanges() manually after search with this.cdr.detectChanges():
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    //...

  searchPosts(): void {

    //...

    .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
      this.dtTrigger.next(null);

      this.cdr.detectChanges();

    });


This is also not working. I have tried. Not sure there is definetely bug in datatable
